# Objective-C: Automatically create Views/ViewController from data structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, nested

I'm starting to write an app to display the following data structure:

- Category #0

  - Subcategory #0.0

    - Item #0.0.0

      - Item description
    - ...
    - Item #0.0.n
  - ...
  - Subcategory #0.n
- ...
- Category #n

In words there are categories with subcategories, which in turn may contain subcategories as well, and so on. The final subcategory contains a list of items and on click a short description should be displayed.

I was thinking about a design just like the native *Settings* app on the iPhone. Everything is included in an Navigation controller and the first categories are displayed. When clicked a new view shows up displaying the subcategories. This goes on until an item is clicked and the description is displayed.

I'm wondering how I could go about implementing this.

1. What is a reliable, scalable way to store the data (like above). I don't want to hardcore the data into an `NSDictionary` of `NSDictionary`'s of `NSString`'s. Maybe something like *JSON* and then use a parser, to write the data into an `NSDictionary`?
2. All the Views/ViewControllers are of the same nature (maybe except the final controller to display the description). They display the list of categories and hold the data to create the VC *one step deeper*. But how can one VC create another VC programmatically and display it? I'm sure there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in any format you like, for instance XML or JSON is OK, the main point is to consider a comfortable structure, like `index = data`. You can pass data from previous VC to the next and track its index

Then you can use it as follows:

Root View Controller with a navigation controller

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *navButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)navigate:(UIButton *)sender
{
    DetailViewController *vc = [DetailViewController new];
    vc.prevIndex = 0;
    vc.dataString = @"data";
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

@end
```

DetailViewController - for showing subcategories/items

DetailViewController.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger prevIndex;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dataString;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 0, 0)];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"navigate from %li", (long)_prevIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(navigate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)navigate
{
    DetailViewController *vc = [DetailViewController new];
    vc.prevIndex = _prevIndex + 1;
    vc.dataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data %li", (long)vc.prevIndex];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

@end
```